# Making a choice based on probability - Python

Tags: python, list, random, methods, probability

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Lets say we have a list like this in Python. I want to continuously print the elements in this list one by one. but I want elements 5 and less than 5 to have an 80% chance of appearing on the screen, and the rest of elements to have a 20% chance of appearing on the screen. How can i do this?

Comment: I did not understand the question?

Comment: Add the output that you wish to get

Comment: If you `import random`, you could do it like: `print(random.choices(my_list, weights=(80,80,80,80,80,20,20,20,20,20), k=10))` k stands for the total print outs.

Comment: @Sujay i will print elements but 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 will have %80 chance to be printed.

output will be only numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost certainly a better solution that this, but this works. It first works out if its going to be in the 20% or 80% for each round (rand) by saying if the random number is 8 or 9 then its in the 20% (2/10), then randomly selects from the corresponding half of the list.

```
import random
rand = random.randrange(0,9)
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
if rand == 8 or rand == 9:
    print(my_list[5:][random.randrange(0,4)])
else:
    print(my_list[:5][random.randrange(0,4)])
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

```
import random

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

print(random.choices(my_list, weights=(80,80,80,80,80,20,20,20,20,20)))
```

Results:

```
[8]
[2]
[2]
[1]
[4]
[5]
```

If you put in the 'k' variable, you can print out as many as k is equal to:

```
print(random.choices(my_list, weights=(80,80,80,80,80,20,20,20,20,20), k=10))
```

Results:

```
[1, 3, 5, 5, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 10]
```